# Infinite loop with random playlist

Tags: javascript, html

I have numerous MP3 files in a folder.

When I enter a page, I want a song from that playlist to play. After this song is over, I want a new one to play (not the same one) and so on.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var song = ["../audio/1.mp3" , "../audio/2.mp3", "../audio/3.mp3", "../audio/4.mp3", "../audio/5.mp3" ];
var soundFile = song[Math.floor(Math.random()*song.length)];
document.write("<embed id='sound' src='" + soundFile + "' loop='true' type='audio/mpeg' controller='false' height='0' width='0'>");
</script>
```

What's wrong, because it always plays the same song.

Comment: I don't think there's any song playing. The string inside `document.write` is messed up.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Are you serving the audio files from a web server with the correct mime type? If not, I suspect this is a bug/undefined behavior from MSIE 11.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an already defined embedded element and set the `src` attribute.

```
<embed id='sound' loop='true' type='audio/mpeg' controller='false' height='0' width='0'>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var songs = ["../audio/1.mp3" , "../audio/2.mp3", "../audio/3.mp3", "../audio/4.mp3", "../audio/5.mp3" ];
  var remainingSongs = songs;
  var el = document.getElementById("sound");

  var pickSong = function(){
    // No songs left?
    if(!remainingSongs.length) {
      remainingSongs = songs;
    }

    // Pick song
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (remainingSongs.length - 1));

    var soundFile = remainingSongs[index];

    // Remove song from array
    remainingSongs.splice(index, 1);

    el.setAttribute("src", soundFile);
  }

  pickSong();
  el.addEventListener("ended", pickSong, false);
</script>
```

Comment: It works (no errors), but always the same song (no random). I try to delete the word "escape" and the same result. :(

Comment: @colombo2003 I've updated my code. Now it selects songs at random and starts playing the next one when the previous is done.

Comment: The problem is not on page load or reload (it's ok, the song are different in this case). The problem is if I stay on the page. The song are played and replayed again. After the first song is played, I want to listen another song, not the same.

Comment: @colombo2003 That should be fixed in the last update.

Comment: Not works for me...! :(  I have an error also: "an error occurred inside a plug-in contained in this page"

Comment: @colombo2003 Could you post your full code and the error message?

Comment: @colombo2003 I fixed a small bug, but I still need to see your full code as the error message you provided isn't related to my code.

Comment: I always have "An error occurred inside a plug-in contained in this page" (it is a plugin error pop-up at refresh the page; not an error code of php page). I tried to put the <script> somewhere into body, or first line into <body>, or somewhere into <head>, but not works.

Comment: Finally, IT WORKS (all browsers, included IE11)!!! :) :)) My bad (stupid)... I added <audio>, and in this tag I put <embed>, and then, after </audio>, the Oleander's <script>. BUT... it happends, sometimes, that the next song is the same (e.g. play 1.mp3, then play 3.mp3, play 3.mp3 again, then 4.mp3, then 1.mp3, theh 5.mp3, again 5.mp3 etc); so.sometimes, the next generated random number is the same with the last. But it is not so annoying. Many THANKS Oleander! ;)

Comment: @colombo2003 That can not happened. Are you using the last code I posted? Also, if my answer is correct, don't forget to accept it by clicking the checkbox next to my answer.

Comment: @colombo2003 I'll rephrase myself; that might happened if there are no more songs and it have to start over again. Then the last song might collide with the next one. Like this "song2", "song1", "song3" no more songs => starts over,  "song3", "song1", "song2" and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You have an off-by-one error. I think it should be:

```
var soundFile = song[(Math.floor((Math.random())*(song.length-1)))];
```

But otherwise this should work. Could be a combination of the erroneous code and weird browser caching?

Also, check the web server you are using to serve the files and clear its cache.

Plus make sure your audio files are actually different.

Also, random chance may be tricking you. Give it a few goes.

This works for me in Chrome Canary on OSX:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    var song = ['./foo.m4a', 'bar.m4a', 'bam.m4a'];
    var soundFile = song[(Math.floor((Math.random())*(song.length-1)))];
    document.write('<embed id="sound" src="' + soundFile + '" loop="true" type="audio/mpeg" controller="false" height="0" width="0">');
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the loop attribute for the `embed` element doesn't know about your array of audio sources. It's just going to loop over the same source file.

Luckily, there is a pretty easy solution. The following will create an Audio element, with the `Audio` constructor, and continue to set a "random" audio source from the `song` array when the previous is done playing. We can do this by listening for the `ended` event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var song = ["../audio/1.mp3" , "../audio/2.mp3", "../audio/3.mp3", "../audio/4.mp3", "../audio/5.mp3" ];
  var audio = new Audio();
  var setSound = function() {
    var soundFile = escape(song[Math.floor(Math.random()*song.length)]);
    audio.setAttribute('src', soundFile);
    audio.play();
  };

  // set initial source
  setSound();
  // set a new source, when current sound is done playing
  audio.addEventListener('ended', setSound, false);
</script>
```

Comment: "an error occurred inside a plug-in contained in this page"

Comment: @colombo2003 I dont think IE supports mp3 which is why you getting the error. Try with a different audio file.

Comment: @colombo2003 Your issue appears to not be a minimal testcase. I have tested the code provided with Google Chrome (Version 46.0.2490.86), which supports, both the Audio element, and MP3 audio encodings--with success. As has been pointed out, this could be an issue of IE 11, or providing an incorrect mime-type. I suggest you debug further to narrow down the issue, or try another browser. Hope this helps.

Comment: Not working with wav and ogg files (converted from mp3 files) :((

Comment: @colombo2003 First ensure that the file is even playable in your browser. Do this by dropping it in your browser.

Comment: Yes, the mp3 file is playable (in quick time player) in my IE 11 browser by url address. Important: I used <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

Comment: IE11: mp3 and wav are played directly (in url), in quick time. ogg is open with winamp. The same files are not played at all in another browser (Mozilla, Chrome, Opera etc).